# jQuery: second dropdown from array based on value of first dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

**Question:** I have two drop-down boxes. Using jQuery, I want to populate second drop-down box on selection of the first drop-down box (help with my existing code). I have marked the area I need help with in the jQuery code below, plus an explanation of what I want to achieve in "Code help".

*I realise this is a VERY frequently requested item on SO and I have seen many comments that this can be done in simple JS, but since there are already other jQuery elements in use on the page (not coded by me) and for simplicity, I want to use JQ.*

I am completely new to any jQuery code, I have researched many examples, however I am getting lost in the logic since I am not familiar with JS or JQ coding conventions, so keeping things simple is important so I can understand what is happening within the code (I am not *just* looking for help to get my code working, but also so I can *learn and understand what is happening*).

I found pretty much exactly the operation I want to achieve (***except for one important point explained in "Code help" below***) by following a tutorial here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/populate-select-boxes/. A sample page showing the operation is here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/select-boxes.html

**Code help:** In the tutorial, the second dropdown is populated from the content of static html files in: `$article.load('select-boxes-' + categoryName + '.html');`
I need the second dropdown to be populated from the JS variable `$st_list` and the PHP variable `$student_block` based on the selected value in the first dropdown, as shown in my code below.

Could anyone please help with how to adapt the code to make that happen?

Thank you

**My code:**
For simplicity, the first dropdown is static with simple integer values, but will be populated from the DB in `$test_seq` in the working code with integer values same as the example code below (if that matters). Additionally, in a separate PHP process (later) the `$test_seq`, `$student_id` and other `new variables` will be used to send back data to the DB *(included for reference only, though not relevant for this request).*

*select-boxes.php*

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
  $test_seq = $row['SEQ'];
  $student_id = $row['st_num'];
  $student_name = $row['st_name'];
  $student_block .= '<OPTION value="'.$student_id.'">'.$student_id.' - '.$student_name.'</OPTION>';
}
```

*Form:*

```
<form action="select-boxes.php">
<label for="test_day">Test day:</label>
   <select name="test_day" id="test_day">
    <option selected value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="1">Day 1</option>
    <option value="2">Day 2</option>
    <option value="3">Day 3</option>
   </select>
<input type="submit" id="next" value="next &raquo;" />
</form>
```

*jQuery:*

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var $test_day = $('#test_day'),
    $st_list = null;
    $test_day.change(function () {
      var test_dayVal = $test_day.val();
      if ($st_list == null) {
        $st_list = $('<select name="st_name" id="st_name"><?php echo $student_block; ?></select>').appendTo('form');
        $next.remove();
        $('form').append('<input type="submit" value="process &raquo;" />');
      }

      $st_list.load('#test_dayVal'); //<--I think this is where I need help.. What do I do here?

    });

    var $next = $('#next');

    $next[0].setAttribute('type', 'button');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I am guessing that you are seeing one selected option after you click next, is this true? If so i'll follow up with an answer about how you cant iterate thru php with an echo in javascript